# How to create bootable application image (efi)?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, boot, uefi

I trying to boot an elf microkernel in an UEFI environment. So i compiled a minimal boot loader and created an ESP image. This works fine if I boot via an HDD but I want to direct boot it via the qemu -kernel option (This is some special requirement as I am working with AMD SEV). This doesn't work.

I can boot my kernel like this with grub if I use grub mkimage with a fat image included i.e. like this:

```
mcopy -i "${basedir}/disk.fat" -- "${basedir}/kernel" ::kernel
mcopy -i "${basedir}/disk.fat" -- "${basedir}/module" ::module

grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi 
             -c "${basedir}/grub-bootstrap.cfg" 
             -m "${basedir}/disk.fat" 
             -o "${basedir}/grub.efi"
```

But the goal for my system is minimalism and security hence the microkernel, so grub and it's vulnerabilities is out of question.

So my question is:
How to create a bootable application image similar to grub-mkimage?

I have read about efi stub boot but couldn't really figure out how to build an efi stub image.

Normally I am a bare metal embedded programmer, so the whole uefi boot thing is a bit weird to me. I am glad for any tips or recommendations. Also I figured stack overflow might not be the best place for such low level questions, can you maybe recommend other forums?

Comment: See https://osdev.org/

Comment: I already read through some articles but couldn't find a way to include an elf and and a bootloader into a single application image, do you know a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to direct boot it via the qemu -kernel option

Why? It's a qemu-specific hack that doesn't exist on anything else (including any real computer). By using this hack the only thing you're doing is failing to test anything you'd normally use to boot (and therefore failing to test anything that actually matters).

> (This is some special requirement as I am working with AMD SEV)

That doesn't make any sense (it's a little bit like saying "I have a banana in my ear because I'm trying to learn how to play piano").

AMD's SEV is a set of extensions intended to enhance the security of virtual machines that has nothing at all to do with how you boot (or whether you boot from BIOS or UEFI or a qemu-specific hack).

> I am glad for any tips or recommendations.

My recommendation is to stop using GRUB specific (multi-boot), Qemu specific (`-kernel`) and Linux/Unix specific (elf) tools and actually try to use UEFI. This will require you to write your own boot loader using (Microsoft's) PE32+ file format that uses UEFI's services itself. Note that GNU's tools (their "Gnu-EFI" stuff for GCC) is relatively awful (it puts a PE32+ wrapper around an ELF file and does run-time patching to make the resulting Franken-monster work); and there are much better alternatives now (e.g. the Clang/LLVM/lld toolchain).

If you care about security, then it'll also involve learning about UEFI SecureBoot (and key management, and digital signatures). If you care about secure virtual machines I'd also recommend learning about the `SKINIT` instruction from AMD"s manual (used to create a dynamic root of trust after boot); but don't forget that this is AMD specific and won't work on any Intel CPU, and is mostly obsolete (the "trusted measurement" stuff from BIOS and TPM was mostly superseded by SecureBoot anyway), and (even on Intel CPUs) if you're only the guest then the hyper-visor can emulate it in any way it wants (and it won't guarantee anything is secure).

Finally; note that booting a micro-kernel directly doesn't make much sense either. There's no device drivers in a micro-kernel; so after booting a micro-kernel you end up with a "can't start any device drivers because there are no device drivers" problem. Instead you need to load many files (e.g. maybe an initial RAM disk), then (e.g.) start some kind of "boot log handler" (to display error messages, etc); then find and start the kernel, then start other processes (e.g. "device manager" to detect devices and drivers; "VFS layer" to handle file systems and file IO; etc). For the whole thing; starting the kernel is just one relatively insignificant small step (not much more than starting a global shared library that provides multi-tasking) buried among a significantly larger amount of code that does all the work.

Sadly; booting a monolithic kernel directly can make sense because it can contain all the drivers (or at least, has enough built into the kernel's executable file to handle an initial RAM disk if it's "modular monolithic" with dynamically loaded drivers); and this "monolithic with stuff that doesn't belong in any micro-kernel" idea is what most beginner tutorials assume.

Comment: Thanks, I now about most of the issues but I will have a look into Clang and LLVM. For now a fast "hacky" solution would be fine for testing though.